# AngularJS - async binding in component

Tags: angularjs

Hello I have this component:

```
zpc.component("myComponent", {
template: '<button ng-click="$ctrl.find()">CLICK</button>\
                {{$ctrl.results|json}}\ //allways empty
            </div>',
controller: function MyComponent($http) {
    this.text = "";
    this.results = [];
    this.find = function () {
        $http.get("https://swapi.co/api/films/1").then(function (response) {
            this.results = response.data;
            console.log(this.results); //here is data
        });
    }
}
});
```

After click data is loaded correctly, but will not appear in the view. How to bind data to view from async? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the callback function to this:

```
$http.get("https://swapi.co/api/films/1").then(function (response) {
    this.results = response.data;
    console.log(this.results); //here is data
}.bind(this));
```

Or avoid using this, and use instead

```
var vm = this;
vm.find = function () {
    $http.get("https://swapi.co/api/films/1").then(function (response) {
        vm.results = response.data;
        console.log(vm.results); //here is data
    });
}
```